# Unable to 'learn' a rotational angle by parametrising the angle as a neural network layer

Tags: deep-neural-networks

I'm trying to implement a neural network that can capture the drift in a measured angle as a way of dynamic calibration. i.e, I have a reference system that may change throughout the course of the data gathering and would like to train a network layer which actually converts the drifting reference to the desired reference by updating the angle parameter.

For example: Consider the 2d case. We would have a set of 2d points $X\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and a trainable parameter called $\theta$ in the layer. The output of the layer would then be:
$$X_o = XR$$ where
$$R = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ 
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}$$

Using Adam optimizer I then try to find the $\theta$ which transforms a given angle to the desired reference.

However, the $\theta$ value seems to fluctuate around the initial value probably because of a diverging gradient(?). How can I overcome this issue?

The code is below.

````
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Rotation2D(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Rotation2D, self).__init__()

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel", initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(90),
                                  shape=[1, 1])

  def call(self, input):
    matrix = ([[tf.cos(self.kernel[0, 0]), -tf.sin(self.kernel[0, 0])],
              [tf.sin(self.kernel[0, 0]), tf.cos(self.kernel[0, 0])]])
    return tf.matmul(input, tf.transpose(matrix))

layer = Rotation2D()

t = np.arange(0, 1000)/200.

y_in = np.array([np.sin(t), np.cos(t)]).T
y_ta = np.array([np.cos(t), np.sin(t)]).T

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layer)

model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1.), loss='MSE')
model.fit(y_in, y_ta, epochs=1)
for i in range(100):
  print(layer.get_weights())
  model.fit(y_in, y_ta,verbose=0, batch_size=5)
y_out = (model.predict(y_in))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1)

for i in range(2):
  ax = axes[i]

  ax.plot(y_in.T[i], label = 'input')
  ax.plot(y_ta.T[i], label = 'target')
  ax.plot(y_out.T[i], label = 'prediction')

plt.legend()

plt.show()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two basic problems with your code:

- The functions `sin(t)` and `cos(t)` (both in numpy and tensorflow) take radians as inputs. Seeing `Constant(90)` in your code, and the learning rate of `1.` I'm guessing that you assume that it is in degrees - that's incorrect.
- In your training data `y_ta` **is not a rotation** of `y_in`:

  ```
  y_in = np.array([np.sin(t), np.cos(t)]).T
  y_ta = np.array([np.cos(t), np.sin(t)]).T
  ```

It is a reflection about `y=x` diagonal. No wonder it fails to find an appropriate rotation.

I just had to change `y_ta` to:

```
  y_ta = np.array([-np.cos(t), np.sin(t)]).T
```

And train with more sensible learning rate:

```
  model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.1), loss='MSE')
  model.fit(y_in, y_ta, epochs=10)
```

To get the angle (which I then convert to degrees):

```
  (180 * model.layers[0].kernel[0,0].numpy() / np.pi) % 360
  > 90.00187079311581
```

Comment: Thanks and yes, I believe I messed up with the target value which was not actually a rotation.